# Find the slope-intercept form of the equation of the line passing through the points. Sketch the line.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

> Find the slope-intercept form of the equation of the line passing through the points. Sketch the line.
>
> 1. (-8,1),(-8,7)
> 2. (-1,4),(6,4)

#### Progress

The slope that I get for number 1 is infinity. I cannot proceed because I don't know how the infinity can be calculated.

Hope you can help me!

Comment: What are your thoughts so far on this problem? Do you know how to calculate slope, given two points? What do you get for the slopes of the two lines?

Comment: The slope that I get for number 1 is infinity. I cannot proceed because I don't know how the infinity can be calculated.

Comment: This means that the slope is undefined.  Notice that both points have x-value -8.  If you plot the two points you get a vertical line.  Do you know the equation for a vertical line?

Comment: Usually, we call that slope "undefined", rather than "infinity". It the slope you get for a vertical line, because you try to do "rise over run", but the amount of "run" is zero. Do you know how equations for vertical lines work?

Comment: In #2, the slope is undefined because in both points $y=4$. Opps! Did I just give away the answer? :o

Comment: If you suspect a vertical line, use $\frac{1}{m} = \frac{\Delta x}{\Delta y}$. If $m=\infty$ then $\frac{1}{m}=0$, which would imply that $\Delta x = 0$

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Let the slope intercept from be $$y=mx+c$$

Set $(-8,1);(-8,7)$ to find two linear simultaneous equation in $m,c$

Answer (score 0):

If (x1,y1) and (x2,y2)be two points in the plane.Then the equation of the line joining these two points is $(y-y1) (x1-x2)=(x-x1)(y1-y2)$.
From this equation you will get slope intercept form.

Answer (score 0):

The formula for slope is
$$\begin{array}{llllr}m=\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}&&&&(1)\end{array}$$
To find the equation of a line passing through 2 points the formula is
$$\begin{array}{llllr}m=\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}&&&&(2)\end{array}$$
For example, if we wanted to find the equation of a line passing through points $(-2, 11)$ and $(3,-4)$ we would first use equation $(1)$  to find the slope.

$$\begin{array}{lllr}
m&=&\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}\\
m&=&\frac{\color{blue}{11} - (-4)}{\color{blue}{-2}-(3)}\\
m&=&\frac{15}{-5}\\
m&=&-3
\end{array}$$

By equation $(2)$ we have

$$\begin{array}{lllr}
-3&=&m\\
-3&=&\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}\\
-3&=&\frac{\color{blue}{y}-(-4)}{\color{blue}{x}-(3)}\text{ or alternatively, } \frac{y-11}{y-(-2)}\\
-3&=&\frac{y+4}{x-3}
\end{array}$$

Next, we have to express the equation in the form $y=mx+b$

$$\begin{array}{lllr}
-3&=&\frac{y+4}{x-3}\\
\frac{y+4}{x-3}&=&-3\\
y+4&=&-3(x-3)\\
y&=&-3(x-3)-4\\
y&=&-3x+9-4\\
y&=&-3x+5
\end{array}$$

We call this *slope-intercept* form because the $-3$ represents the *slope*, and the $5$ represents the *y-intercept*.
Notice that you can also express the equation in this form.
$$\begin{array}{lllr}
y&=&-3x+5\\
y-5&=&-3x\\
\frac{y-5}{-3}&=&x\\
x&=&\frac{y-5}{-3}\\
x&=&-\frac{1}{3}y+\frac{5}{3}\\
\end{array}$$
Where $-1/3$ is the slope's reciprocal (i.e. $1/m$), and $5/3$ is the $x-intercept$.

By the way, did anyone notice that $(1$) and $(2)$ are the same formula?